Error using Eigen: "mismatched types" with scalar vector multiplication
I am trying to perform the following operation from MATLAB using Eigen matrices in C++.
Given an example in MATLAB:
clearvars; clc; close all;
Nx = 8; 
Ny = 8;
Lx=2*pi;
dx = Lx/Nx;
Vec  = fftshift(-Nx/2:Nx/2-1);
Vector1 = (sin( Vec * dx/2)/(dx/2)).^2 ;

[Matrix2,x] = cheb(Ny);
 for m = 1:length(Vec)
        Matrix1 = -1 * (Vector1(m))+ Matrix2;
    end

The function Cheb in MATLAB:
function [ D, x ] = cheb ( N )
  if ( N == 0 )
    D = 0.0;
    x = 1.0;
    return
  end

  x = cos ( pi * ( 0 : N ) / N )';
  c = [ 2.0; ones(N-1,1); 2.0 ] .* (-1.0).^(0:N)';
  X = repmat ( x, 1, N + 1 );
  dX = X - X';
%  Set the off diagonal entries.
  D =( c * (1.0 ./ c )' ) ./ ( dX + ( eye ( N + 1 ) ) );

  D = D - diag ( sum ( D' ) );

  return
end

Where, Matrix1 and Matrix2 both have the same size (Ny+1 by Ny+1) and are square matrices and Vector1 is a row-vector with the size of 1 by Nx, as well as Vec is a row-vector with size of 1 by Nx.
Now, in Eigen I usually cannot simply perform the above operation and so for example:
Eigen code:
static const int nx = 8;
static const int ny = 8;

Eigen::MatrixXcd Matrix1((ny+1),(ny+1));
Matrix1.setZero();
Eigen::MatrixXd Matrix2((ny+1),(ny+1));
Matrix2.setZero(); 

Eigen::MatrixXd Vec((1),nx);
Vec.setZero();
Eigen::MatrixXd Vector1((1),nx);
Vector1.setZero();
for (int l = 0; l < (Vec.size()-1); l++){                    
                    Matrix1 = -1. * Vector1(l)+ Matrix2;//error here
}

In the past I was able to initialize Vector1 as a "matrix" then use something like Vector1.asDiagona() but I don't think it works here. Is there an easier way to multiply by a -1?
Full error:
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >, 1>::Scalar’ {aka ‘double’} and ‘Eigen::MatrixXd’ {aka ‘Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>’})


how does MATLAB interpret Matrix1 = -1 * Vector1 + Matrix2; ? Its not obvious, because mathematically you cannot add that vector to that matrix. And thats why the direct translation to Eigen also fails

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Sorry, I just edited the question. MATLAB iterates through length of vector Vec and it returns a square matrix.

Are imports useful when posting code on answers?

its still not obvious what the code does. You add a scalar to a matrix. What does that mean?

trying to translate code between two different languages usually fails when done literally. You need to understand what the code does and then implement the same in the other langauge. The result potentially has little in common with the original. If Matrix1 = -1 * Vector1(m) + Matrix2; actually works in MATLAB, then only because its MATLABs fancy way to let you write some operation. Though what that operation is can only be understood by someone familiar with MATLAB.

" Is there an easier way to multiply by a -1?" the multiplication of the scalar with -1 works fine, its the addition that fails

Post a [mcve]..

@463035818_is_not_an_ai no the multiplication by -1 doesn't work fine in Eigen and it still returns the same error.

The error you quote is not about the multiplication but about the +. In addition it is still unclear what you want to happen when you do scalar + Matrix

There is a whole lot of stuff that is weird or wrong with your C++ code but the main issue is really that it is unclear what you want to happen. Can you spell it out as a simple scalar loop? One thing that comes to mind is Matrix1 = Matrix2.rowwise() - Vector1; but for that a) you should use the proper type Eigen::RowVectorXd Vector1 and it would need to have the same dimensions as Matrix2. Or maybe Matrix1.topRows(nx) = Matrix2.topRows(nx).rowwise() - Vector1?

The MATLAB code makes no sense. You are overwriting Matrix1 repeatedly in that loop, only the last loop iteration is meaningful. At the end of the loop, Matrix1 is -1 * (Vector1(end))+ Matrix2, more succinctly written as Matrix2 - Vector1(end).

For all commenters here, note that Vector1(m) is a scalar value, and adding it to a matrix means adding it to each element of the matrix.

@CrisLuengo That whole line Matrix1 = -1 * (Vector1(m))+ Matrix2; is confusing. Why the extra parentheses? Why not Matrix2 - Vector1(m)?

@Mathew77 If you isolate your code to the one line that is causing the error, you can track down the problem. Create a matrix and a scalar, and execute that one line. Try the multiplication only. Does that work? Try the addition only. Does that work? That is the only code that is necessary to reproduce your problem. Everything else is a distraction and not part of a [mre].

@beaker I have tried isolating the code, and no the multiplication by a scalar alone does not work:  Matrix1 = -1. * Vector1(l);  nor addition only! It must be an Eigen library thing where scalar addition and/or multiplication must be handled differently.

@CrisLuengo Yes I understand the MATLAB code does not necessarily make sense because during each iteration, Matrix1  is overwritten with the result of the scalar -1 * (Vector1(m)) added to the matrix Matrix2 but the point I am getting at is how to perform scalar addition/multiplication with a matrix in Eigen.

If that's your question, I've linked to a Q&A that asks and answers exactly that. For multiplication, you can just do matrix * scalar.

@CrisLuengo Thanks! Actually, I think that solves my issue.

Matrix1 = -1. * Vector1(l); is not mutliplication only. It is multiplication of a scalar with a scalar, which one would execpt to be fine, and assignment to a matrix of different dimensions, which one would expect to produce an error
